# MX4 bluetooth disconnects immediately

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, connection, meizu-mx4

I tried to connect my new Ubuntu MX4 by bluetooth to a Samsung Android. The two devices were able to connect, establish password confirmation - but they disconnected after ten- twenty seconds.

Anyone sharing this problem - do you know what to do  - and would you direct me to where I can report it as a bug?